# fopen outputs invalid argument when passing text file name to it after parsing the name from url which was encoded using urlencode

Tags: php

```
$rootPath = "data/subset1/";
$fileName = $_GET["fn"];
$filePath = $rootPath.$fileName;
$myfile = fopen($filePath, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

I am using the following line to encode the url

```
$link = 'http://'.$ip.'set/file.php?fn='.urlencode($line);
```

where `$line = "textfile.txt"`.

I encoded the `fn` part of the url using `urlencode`. When I `echo $filePath`, the path is exactly as it should be and `fopen` succeeds  when I manually type the output of `echo $filePath` as the argument of `fopen`, but fails, when using `$filePath` as the argument.
`file_exist()` displays a similar behaviour where the argument `$filePath`results a `FALSE`, but manually entering the path into `file_exists()` results a `TRUE`. I understand there is a systematic error of some sort but I am not sure what this error is. I have tried the alternatives such [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) but this doesn't encode spaces. [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) seems to be the only one that takes care of all the special characters I throw at it. Does this have anything to do with charactersets? If so, I have tried using `utf8_decode($line)` and that didn't change the results either.

Comment: @Gargoyle No you don't, PHP does that automatically when creating `$_GET`.

Comment: I'll bet there's a non-printing character in `$line`, like a space or newline.

Comment: @Barmar is correct if you scroll down on the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) page it say that $_GET decodes it.

Comment: Instead of `echo $filePath`, use `var_dump($filePath)`. This will show the length, and I'll bet the length won't match the number of characters you can see.

Comment: @Barmar There are indeed spaces in some of the text file names but there are other text files which are one word only; but no newline. The behaviour exists for all cases. And based on the documentation urlencode replaces space with a + so space shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Did you try my `var_dump` test?

Comment: I just did, and there are indeed 2 extra characters for all inputs.

Comment: Are you reading `$line` from a file with `fgets()` or `file()`? I think you forgot to strip off the newline at the end of the line.

Comment: Does fgets() adds these extra characters? `$line = fgets($myfile)`

Comment: Read the documentation: `Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF`. It says that the newline is included in the return value.

Comment: I didn't even know about this. I am very new to php so thank you for helping me learn something new :). And I apologise if this was a waste of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$line` ends with a newline, which needs to be stripped off.

```
$line = trim(fgets($myfile));
```